# Use COPY in Dockerfile to copy a file to the ROOT

Tags: docker

I am trying to write a simple Dockerfile, similar to hello-world.

The image attached shows:

1. The hello-world Dockerfile
2. My Dockerfile
3. The results of `docker build`

The syntax in my Dockerfile appears to be identical to the one from hello-world, yet no matter what combination of paths I use, I can't just COPY `hello.sh` to the root of the image.  I **can** copy it to a subfolder using different syntax.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Is there a `.dockerignore` file in that directory? `ls -al` output may help.

Comment: @BMitch no, there is no .dockerignore.

Comment: do you try `COPY hello.sh /subfolder/../` ?)